# Office add-in is not activated on Outlook if open .msg template

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

My add-in has a `MessageComposeCommandSurface ExtensionPoint` that adds a button to the ribbon when the user is composing a message and `MessageReadCommandSurface` for the read mode.

I expected the button to always be enabled when it is visible (e.g. when the user is composing a new message or replying to an existing one).

Works perfectly, but my add-in is greyed out/disabled when opening a **template (save a message as a template and open .msg file with outlook)**.

1. Add-in is greyed out if .msg was saved from composing mode.
2. Add-in is disabled if.msg was saved from read mode.

Does anyone know the why an add-in ribbon button is greyed out/disabled when opening a .msg template (open in a read mode)? At the same time, add-in is available when reply/forward, etc. for just opened .msg template.

Comment: I would like to clarify ... Are you talking about Outlook Template format, which is `.oft` or regular Outlook message format (not template), which is `.msg`?

Comment: regular message format, which is .msg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Also you can move *.msg files to folders. Click on the Tab **File** -> **Move to Folder** ->**Copy to Folder** choose particular folder. When msg was moved to folder go to your outlook and add-in is available. I hope that was useful for you.

Comment: If you'd like this feature to be implemented, please vote https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/34578595-outlook-add-ins-are-not-supported-in-msg-files-or

Answer (score 2):

Add-ins are grayed out/disabled because they are not supported in .msg files nor in message templates.

Comment: but is there any workaround? Our Clients are using saved .msg as a template and would like to use add-in when open .msg. Maybe message can be saved in any other format (add-in to be enabled)?

Comment: @SamLewis Build COM/VSTO add-in. This one will work with stored messages.

Comment: what about eml file? I guess it is not supported either?

Answer (score 1):

Add-in is enabled for Outlook Template (*.OFT), so need to open and save the message as outlook template with .oft format.