# Outlook web add-in commands greyed out when opening an eml file

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

So I have developed a outlook web add-in, it can read emails content and send it to the server.
But, if I use outlook desktop version to open an eml file, the add-in commands will be greyed out. 
Is there any way I can Address this? Because users could potentially want to send contents in eml to the server too.
The below picture show another web add-in get greyed out when I use Outlook desktop to open a eml file.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.msg and .eml files are not suported by web add-ins. 
Similar question:[Office add-in is not activated on Outlook if open .msg template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50879710/office-add-in-is-not-activated-on-outlook-if-open-msg-template)

I don't know of any workaround for this.
If you'd like this feature to be implemented, please vote for [User voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/34578595-outlook-add-ins-are-not-supported-in-msg-files-or).